# mock usePrompt in react-router-dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-router-dom, react-test-renderer

**Prompt.js**

```
import { unstable_usePrompt as usePrompt } from 'react-router-dom';

// eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
export default function Prompt({ when, message }) {
  usePrompt({ when, message });
  return null;
}
```

**Prompt.test.js**

```
import {
  createMemoryRouter,
  RouterProvider,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import Prompt from '../Prompt';


const mockedUsePrompt = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  unstable_usePrompt: () => mockedUsePrompt,
}));

describe('Prompt', () => {
  it('should call usePrompt with parameter', () => {
    const router = createMemoryRouter(
      [
        {
          path: '/',
          element: <Prompt when message="Are you sure?" />,
        },
      ],
      { initialEntries: ['/'] },
    );
    const component = renderer.create(
      <RouterProvider router={router} />,
    );
    const tree = component.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();

    expect(mockedUsePrompt).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ when: true, message: 'Are you sure?' });
  });
});
```

How can I check calling usePrompt with arguments?

this line *expect(mockedUsePrompt).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ when: true, message: 'Are you sure?' });* doesn't work

Comment: Is there a reason you are unit testing code you don't own?

Comment: Actually Prompt is my component and I want to check just call usePrompt with argument which was passed

Comment: What is the purpose of your `Prompt` component that doesn't render anything and only calls the `usePrompt` with the same arguments that were passed to it as props? I don't mean to question your code but it seems rather pointless IMO, you could/should just use `usePrompt` directly where you need it.

Comment: Because it is wrapper, further I use Prompt in the class component not a functional

Comment: I don't see it wrapping anything since it returns `null`, but if you need to do it this way because you are still using React class components then I guess it is what it is. I suspect you have incorrectly mocked the hook, try `unstable_usePrompt: mockedUsePrompt`.

Comment: I've tried, but anyway the same error

Comment: Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) (*or similar*) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: I've created repositoty in github https://github.com/LexaDel/test_prompt_component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mock `unstable_usePrompt` correctly. See below working example:

`Prompt.js`:

```js
import { unstable_usePrompt as usePrompt } from 'react-router-dom';

console.log(" ~ file: Prompt.js:2 ~ usePrompt:", usePrompt)

export default function Prompt({ when, message }) {
  usePrompt({ when, message });
  return null;
}
```

`Prompt.test.js`:

```js
import { createMemoryRouter, RouterProvider, unstable_usePrompt } from 'react-router-dom';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import Prompt from './Prompt';

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  unstable_usePrompt: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('Prompt', () => {
  it('should call usePrompt with parameter', () => {
    const router = createMemoryRouter(
      [
        {
          path: '/',
          element: <Prompt when message="Are you sure?" />,
        },
      ],
      { initialEntries: ['/'] },
    );
    renderer.create(<RouterProvider router={router} />);
    expect(unstable_usePrompt).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ when: true, message: 'Are you sure?' });
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
  console.log
     ~ file: Prompt.js:2 ~ usePrompt: [Function: mockConstructor] {
      _isMockFunction: true,
      getMockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
      mock: [Getter/Setter],
      mockClear: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReset: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockRestore: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReturnValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReturnValue: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockResolvedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockRejectedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockImplementationOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReturnThis: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockName: [Function (anonymous)],
      getMockName: [Function (anonymous)]
    }

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/Prompt/Prompt.js:2:9)

 PASS  src/Prompt/Prompt.test.js
  Prompt
    ✓ should call usePrompt with parameter (9 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.176 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites matching /\/home\/lindu\/workspace\/mrdulin\/test_prompt_component\/src\/Prompt\/Prompt.test.js/i.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```